# C - If statement not working

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement

I was creating a program to print all the prime numbers from an array.
So, Everything works correctly except the if statement to skip the numbers smaller than 2 which are obviously not prime numbers.
Here's the code:

```
int main()
{
int a[10], i, prime = 0, c = 0;

printf("Enter 10 numbers:\n");

for( i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    scanf(" %d", &a[i]);
}

printf("Prime numbers are:");
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    prime = 1;
for(c = 2; c < a[i]; c++)
{
    if(a[i] < 2)
    {
    prime = 0;
    break;
    }


    if(a[i] % c == 0)
    {
    prime = 0;
    break;
    }


}
if(prime == 1)
printf("%d, ",a[i]);
}

}
```

Here, the statement:

```
if(a[i] < 2)
{
prime = 0;
break;
}
```

does not work.

I also added a printf statement in the if block but it doesn't get executed.
What's the cause of this problem and how to solve it?

Comment: "*I also added a printf statement in the if block but it doesn't get executed.*" To immediately see debug-output print it stderr always (`fprintf, stderr, ...);`, as this stream is ***un***buffered. Alternatively, after each call to `ptrintf()` place a ` fflush(stdout)`.

Comment: `for` loop will not be entered when `a[ i ] < 2`.

Comment: Put the `printf` statement **outside** the if block: `printf("in a[i], i is %d and a[%d] is %d.\n", i, i, a[i]);`

Comment: @Ashar7  Try to change the computer!

Comment: @Ashar7  Take into account that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like int main( void )

Comment: @xing
Stupid Me!
Thnx, I added that if statement into the outer loop and removed the break.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow 
But not declaring it like that wouldn't cause any issue.(At least in this program)

Comment: @Ashar7 You should follow the Standard.

Comment: The posted code does not compile!  Amongst other things, it is missing the needed `#include` statements.  Do you expect us to guess as to what your actual code includes? The posted code does not check for I/O errors.

Comment: @user3629249 Sorry but I use gcc compiler and it isn't necessary to include stdio or conio files in that compiler

Comment: I also use `gcc`, with the parameters: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu11.  Here is the result: ":5:1: warning: implicit declaration of function 'printf' {-Wimplicit-function-declaration]  5:1: warning: imcompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf;'  5:1: note: include '<stdio.h>' or provide a declaration of 'printf'  9:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'scanf'' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]  9:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'scanf'  9:5: note: include '<stdio.>' or provide a declaration of 'scanf'

Comment: cont: the above output was produced by the compiler when I copy/paste the posted code into the compiler.  Especially notice the statements about the INCOMPATIBLE declarations of the functions.  Note, I left off the echo's of the source lines, the file name, etc in the above messages to fit into a single comment box.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Checking out my question after 3 years and boy was I stupid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

It is much better to use a named constant instead of a magic number. So it is desirable at least to introduce such a constant like

```
#define N 10
```

and use it everywhere instead of the number 10.

The array should have type `unsigned int` because prime numbers belong to natural numbers.

Due to the condition in the for loop

```
for(c = 2; c < a[i]; c++)
           ^^^^^^^^
```

inside the body of the loop `a[i]` is always greater than 2. So this if statement

```
if(a[i] < 2)
```

does not make sense.

You could reduce the number of iterations of the inner loop.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10

int main( void )
{
    unsigned int a[N];

    printf("Enter %zu numbers: ", ( size_t )N);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        scanf("%u", &a[i]);
    }

    printf("Prime numbers are: ");

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        int prime = a[i] == 2 || a[i] % 2 == 1 && a[i] != 1;

        for (unsigned int j = 3; prime && j <= a[i] / j; j += 2)
        {
            prime = a[i] % j != 0;
        }

        if (prime) printf("%u, ", a[i]);
    }

    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter 10 numbers: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Prime numbers are: 2, 3, 5, 7,
```

Answer (score 2):

you are never entering the for loop

```
for(c = 2; c < a[i]; c++)
```

if values of a[i]= 1 and a[i]=2 and your inner if loop

```
if(a[i] < 2)
```

is checking for values less than 2 so you cant enter the if loop

Answer (score 1):

Your code after some changes -

- Check if the number is less than 2 before entering the inner loop.
- To check primality you are not required to go upto `a[i] -1`. You can check if any number up to square root `a[i]` is divisible or not. This is to increase the efficiency otherwise your approach is also correct.

  ```
   int main()
   {
      int a[10], i, prime = 0, c = 0;
      printf("Enter 10 numbers:\n");

      for( i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
         scanf(" %d", &a[i]);
      } 

       printf("Prime numbers are:");
       for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
       {
          if(a[i]<2)
              continue;

          prime = 1;

          for(c = 2; c*c <= a[i]; c++)
          {
              if(a[i] % c == 0)
              {
                 prime = 0;
                 break;
              }
           }
           if(prime == 1)
             printf("%d, ",a[i]);
       }

   }
  ```

For other approaches to check primality you can visit the following links -

- Fermat's Method - http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/primality-test-set-2-fermet-method/
- Miller Rabin Method - http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/primality-test-set-3-miller-rabin/
- Sieve of Eratosthenes - http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/primality-test-set-3-miller-rabin/

Answer (score 1):

the main problem is the output is printed when the inner loop is exited because the value was less than 2.

Here is a version of the code that :

1. performs the desired operation
2. outputs the correct values
3. properly checks for errors
4. cleanly compiles

and now the code

```
#include <stdio.h>   // printf(), scanf(), perror()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

#define ARRAY_LEN 10

int main( void )
{
    int a[ ARRAY_LEN ];

    int prime = 0;


    printf("Enter 10 numbers:\n");

    for( int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LEN; i++)
    {
        if( 1 != scanf(" %d", &a[i]) )
        {
            perror( "scanf failed" );
            exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }

    printf("Prime numbers are: ");

    for( int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LEN; i++)
    {
        prime = 1;

        if(a[i] < 2)
        {
            prime = 0;

        }

        else
        {

            for( int c = 2; c < a[i]; c++)
            {



                if(a[i] % c == 0)
                {
                    prime = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if(prime == 1)
            printf("%d, ",a[i]);
    }
    puts( "" );
} // end function: main
```

Here is the inputs I used and the outputs from a run of the code:

```
Enter 10 numbers:
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Prime numbers are: 2, 3, 5, 7,
```